# HTTP module does not execute

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to receive a string from a server in android app, but the code does not execute and even the console.log does not print anything

```
const httpModule = require("tns-core-modules/http");
function requestList()
    {


httpModule.getString("https://******.php").then(

(r) => {console.log("I am at the request function ");//This line is not printed
 },
(e) => {console.log("I am at the request function too ");//This is not printed too 
        }
);


console.log("This the end of the function"); //This line is printed OK
    }
```

I don not receive any error message related to this

At least the console.log must be shown so I can tell that this module is actually working in my app

Comment: Which platform you are testing, what is your end point, is it localhost or some ip or domain?

Comment: It is a domain, which works fine when visited from a browser, and give the expected results

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue with Playground? Can you share it?

Comment: Ok I made new project using playground, now I got a connection error,

https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.52520680.1147649310.1553014141-1869802547.1553014141&template=play-js&id=c3wBtK

Comment: I don't see any error, `[[...]0]: This the end of the function
[[... (497)]0]: [{"id_restaurants":"resturant_Al-souq_sadaf"},{"id_restaurants":"resturant_indust_abuMaktoom"}]
[[... (497)]0]: I am at the request function`

Comment: I got this:
Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7e500b7d08: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Comment: I think it must be something with your device / network, it might not be accepting your domain's SSL.

Comment: ok, I will try another device and maybe I will use another domain, Thank you for your help and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after creating a playground project I was able to communicate with the server, 
also I should have used wait and async in my original code, so it is a newbie mistake after all